# how to catch id in aspx page in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on a MVC production project.

In my Production details view I have some buttons to get some more data from the database, but for this I need the id of the Product. I can see it exist but can I catch it?

Here's my controller that return data:

```
 public ActionResult Details(long AProductionOrderId)
    {

        ProductionOrderList item = new ProductionOrderList();
        item = ProductionOrderReg.GetProductionOrders(conn, AProductionOrderId);
        ViewData["item"] = item;
        return View();
    }
```

Here's my details page when it load, I can see the id, but how to catch and use it in the buttons in the left to bring more date ?

[image]

Comment: Please make an effort to write in proper English - you could at least fix the typos

Comment: What do you have for routing routes?

Comment: Just put the id into ViewData and let the buttons use it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hidden input on your view page to submit the ID.

your View:

```
<form method="post">
    <button type="submit">Button Text</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="AProductionOrderId" value="@ViewData['item']">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

i wrote this im my controller

```
ViewData["id"] = AProductionOrderId;
```

and catched it in my view

```
 long id = Convert.ToInt64( ViewData["id"]);
```

Comment: Why don't you pass your model to you view??? I mean you're getting the item in your controller and it has to have the ID property so do Return View(item); and then define the model on your view and you have what you need? Why are you using the ViewData???

Answer (score 0):

If you controller is:

```
public ActionResult Details(long AProductionOrderId)
{
    var item = ProductionOrderReg.GetProductionOrders(conn, AProductionOrderId);
    ViewBag.ProductionOrderId = AProductionOrderId;
    return View(item);
}
```

then your AProductionOrderId will be in the ViewBag although I don't see the reason why you need it since whatever the type of item is (single object instance or list of objects) it contains your ID as a property because you're fetching the item by this ID. Anyway in your model you then need to declare your model like this:

```
 @model YourModelNamespace.ProductionOrderList
```

and now you can access any property of your model in your view. But if you really want you can access it via ViewBag like this:

```
 @{
    long AProductionOrderId = Viewbag.AProductionOrderId;
 }
```